# Html.BeginForm is not sending back the whole data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have asked very similar question but now I narrow down the external factor and now I hope that someone would be able to point me what I am doing wrong and why I don't get the expected result.

In my controller I get data from the database :

```
List<MCS_DocumentFields> model = (List<MCS_DocumentFields>)DocumentFieldService.GetFieldsForDocument(documentId);
```

Make some ordering and passing the List to my view:

```
var finalModel = model
                .OrderBy(c => c.ContentTypeId)
                .ThenBy(c => c.RowNo)
                .ThenBy(c => c.ColumnNo)
                .ThenBy(c => c.MCS_Fields.Order)
                .ToList();
            return View(finalModel);
```

at this point `finalModel` is of type `List<MCS_DocumentFields>`.

My view is this:

```
@model List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Document";
}
<div id="drawForm">

@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethodName", "Forms"))
{
    <table border="1">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model[i].FieldValue))
            {
                <tr>
                <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].FieldValue)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].FieldValue)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Id)
                </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>   
}
</div>
```

This is rendering and I see in the browser about 15 rows with data. When I submit the data to my controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionMethodName(List<MCS_DocumentFields> collection)
{
    var test = collection;
    //Some other code
}
```

With this specific code in the view I get back 1 record from 15 rendered on the page.

However if I change my view like this :

```
<table border="1">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Model[i].ContentTypeId == 1)
            {
                <tr>
                <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].FieldValue)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].FieldValue)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Id)
                </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
```

And to be more specific - `if (Model[i].ContentTypeId == 1)` I get 10 records (there are 10 indeed for this ContentTypeId)

And if I make the view like this :

```
<table border="1">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {

                <tr>
                <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].FieldValue)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].FieldValue)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Id)
                </td>
                </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

No check at all, just iterating all the records - I get back all records(43) to my controller - nothing is missing.

It's very confusing - I'm working with one single entity, just checking for different property values and getting different result every time. And if I don't perform any check at all then I get everything back... what may cause this.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the index field. Your list can work, but the ModelBinder stops at the first gap in the indexes.

See [Phil Haacked's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) on how to solve it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="cold" />
<input type="text" name="products[cold].Name" value="Beer" />
<input type="text" name="products[cold].Price" value="7.32" />
```

There at `cold` you'll want to put your `@i`. Please note that this will cause the posted list to be collapsed: if your list item at index `0` was not posted, the next one that was (for example `1`) will be at index `0`, but I see your `Id` field will take care of that.

That being said, I do agree with @Jason: you won't have this problem when you make sure the model you pass is the model you want to display; I ran into this issue myself when re-ordering a viewmodel clientside and then posting it back.

Comment: Lol, you won't believe how much time I spent on this! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please review [this blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx), specifically the section regarding skipping array indexes and what happens when that occurs.

Basically, because you are only rendering some of the items in the collection, the model binding is failing due to missing indexes.  As I said in my comment on your other question, you would be better served by removing the logic out of the view (where it does not belong anyway).

Create a ViewModel, which is just a simple class.  In that ViewModel, define properties for each of the collections you want to display.  In the controller, split the big collection up into the smaller collections and assign them to the properties in the ViewModel.  Pass the ViewModel to the View and write very simple code to display the data contained there.

When that is done, your loop in your view will be exactly like the last example, and everything will work properly.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to find workaround but now I see that I must take different approach I wasn't ready to understand your previous post, but now I think I get it, at least the most of it. Thanks a lot.